# Measurements for 2017

Tags: mathematics, seasonal

Just your basic New Year's puzzle.

What do the following quantities have in common?

- 6 gigabytes
- 35 hours
- 50 hours
- 1 millimeter
- 3 imperial gallons

Cryptic hint:

> Briefly, cover your bases.

Explicit hint:

> Use abbreviations, and think "basic" in a mathematical sense.

Comment: None of them are divisible by 2017.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Legit.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp#q=35%20hours%20%2F%202017

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They all are

> Equal to 2017 in different bases, using unit abbreviations

6 gigabytes

> 6GB (base 17) -> 2017 (base 10)

35 hours

> 35H (base 25) -> 2017 (base 10)

50 hours

> 50H (base 20) -> 2017 (base 10)

1 millimeter

> 1MM (base 35) -> 2017 (base 10)

3 imperial gallons

> 3IG (base 23) -> 2017 (base 10)